# hibernate trouble with finding last element in table

Tags: hibernate, hql

i try to find last element inserted to table.

i tried to write it like this:

```
m_query = m_session.createQuery("LAST(bankAccount) FROM AccountStatus");
```

the name of wanted record is bankAccount and the name of table is AccountStatus

how should i write it correctly?

thank a lot,

p.s

this is an hibernate query

eli

Comment: If your data shall record history of changes, consider `Hibernate Envers` a module bundled in Hibernate (since 3.5 or 3.6). It is the way to store a data in different times, and query it at specific time.

Answer (score 2):

if you have id in your table you can find last element by max id

```
m_query = m_session.createQuery("max(id) FROM AccountStatus");
```

Comment: That would only return the max id form the AccountStatus Table. To return the LAST(bankAccount) you'll have to use a subquery

Comment: `m_query = m_session.createQuery("a.bankAccount FROM AccountStatus a where a.id = (select max(id) from AccountStatus)");` or `m_query = m_session.createQuery("a.bankAccount FROM AccountStatus a order by a.id desc limit 1");`

Comment: This works only if the ids are guaranteed to be sequential. It will not work if the db reserves and releases blocks of ids for transactions (like e.g. MSSQL can do).

Answer (score 1):

"Tables" in the relational model have set semantics. There is no "last" element, the sorting can be arbitrary. You need to introduce a sort criterium like a timestamp for the insertion date. There are different possible implementations. You could do it on the Java object model by a simple read-only (for the user, not Hibernate!) field that gets initialized to the current time, by a trigger on database level or by a Hibernate lifecycle listener. Then you could easily get the entity with the latest insertion date.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists an autoincrement id column in your table, you can also use:

```
m_query = m_session.createQuery("a1.bankAccount FROM AccountStatus a1 where not exists (a2.bankAccount FROM AccountStatus a2 where a2.id>a1.id)");
```